# Can you always replace mutually recursive references with parameters?

Tags: coq, inductive-type

This is a follow up to a question someone else previously posted: [Expressivity of mutual/nested inductives vs. regular inductives](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/916/expressivity-of-mutual-nested-inductives-vs-regular-inductives).

pigworker answered that

> Adopting Agda-ish notation, the basic strategy is to turn your bunch of mutually defined inductive types into a single inductively defined universe, indexed over its collection of sorts...
>
> ...
>
> BEFORE
>
> ```
> mutual
>   data Even : Set where
>     zero : Even
>     suco : Odd -> Even
>
>   data Odd  : Set where
>     suce : Even -> Odd
> ```
>
> AFTER
>
> ```
> data Sort : Set where
>   even odd : Sort
>
> data Stuff : Sort -> Set where
>   zero : Stuff even
>   suco : Stuff odd -> Stuff even
>   suce : Stuff even -> Stuff odd
>
> Even = Stuff even
> Odd  = Stuff odd
> ```

However, Twitter user @JulesJacobs5 offers a [different approach](https://twitter.com/JulesJacobs5/status/1498728169104453634):

> In Coq you can sometimes parameterize one inductive with some T, and then use the parameterized one in the definition of the other one ...

For example, using the even-odd example, we could take this mutually-defined example:

```ml
Inductive odd : Set := suce (e : even)
with even : Set := zero | suco (o : odd).
```

...and turn it into this non-mutual version:

```ml
Inductive make_odd (even_placeholder : Set) : Set :=
  | suce (e : even_placeholder)
.

Inductive even : Set :=
  | zero
  | suco (o : make_odd even)
.

Definition odd := make_odd even.
```

My question: Can we take *any* mutually-defined inductive type, and "de-mutualize" it via this "Replace all mutual references with a parameter" technique?

If not, what is an example where this technique would fail? A concrete code example would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm not interested in whether such a "de-mutualizing" technique would make proofs more or less tedious. I'm purely interested in whether or not this particular technique can always be applied.

Comment: This produces nested inductives though, which imo is worse than mutual inductives in both theory and application.

Comment: @Trebor Do you think nested inductives are always worse, or only in certain contexts? I agree that in the above example, the mutual definition is nicer than the nested version. However, compare `Ind tree := node : (list tree) -> tree` to `Mutual[tree,tlist] := node : tlist -> tree | tnil : tlist | tcons : tree -> tlist -> tlist`. I'd argue that the first (nested) encoding is better than the second (mutual) encoding, since you can reuse all of `list`'s functions and theorems, without having to reimplement them for `tlist`.

Comment: It is indeed the first thought that you can reuse functions, but turns out you can't in some of the cases! It poses difficulties for termination checking. Coq already had a rule to deal with this, it works well but doesn't cover more advanced cases. For other theorem proves that doesn't have the rule it's worse.